# Syntax is right but runs terribly slow. How could I improve this piece of code?

Tags: python, nlp

```
def vocab(text):
   vocab = [w for w in text if w not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english') 
           and w.isalpha()]
   fd = nltk.FreqDist(vocab)
   print([w for w, n in fd.most_common(50)])

# Define a function that returns the 50 most frequent words in a text
# (filtering out stopwords and punctuation).
```

Code works fine but is terribly slow.
It is a simple function and should not take so long to respond.
I wonder if there is a way speed it up.

Comment: Which bit of it is slow?

Comment: Take `nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english') ` outside the loop, make it a set perhaps? Test `isalpha()` first?

Comment: try to store this nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english') into list and perform with list. because if you call vocal method n times it stopwords calculated n times. this might improve your performance

Comment: @MohamedThasinah A set would be better because it's O(1) lookup, instead of O(n_stopwords).

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy- Thanks for correcting me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

```
import collections   # We'll use `collections.Counter`; it could be optimized
# Make a set of the stopwords, and don't recompute it for
# each invocation of `vocab`
stopword_set = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))

def vocab2(text):
    # Flip the order of stopword testing and isalpha;
    # we assume isalpha is faster, and since `and` is short-circuited,
    # if it returns False, the stopword testing is not done.
    text = [w for w in text if w.isalpha() and w not in stopword_set]
    return [w for w, n in collections.Counter(text).most_common(50)]
```

Timeit says the new version is about 140 times faster:

```
original 1.2306433910052874
fixed 0.008700065001903567
```

Comment: I understand. I thought everything had to be defined inside the function. Thank you for showing me how to use timeit.

Comment: I agree with what you said mostly (it's what I suggested in my comment on the original question), but why use `Counter` here rather than the intended method? I think `fd.most_common()` uses `Counter` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which part of your code is slow, but here is a possibility.

`nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')` returns a list. You can speed you your code by putting its contents in a set before you start iterating through your text.

```
stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
vocab = [w for w in text if w not in stopwords and w.isalpha()]
```

Looking something up in a set is usually really fast.

Comment: Probably worth adding quick comment on why this is helpful, e.g. set time complexity vs. list